# Extracting text headers with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to extract the text headers listed in this Army Field Manual. I first converted it to an html file with adobe acrobat:

http://usacac.army.mil/sites/default/files/misc/doctrine/CDG/cdg_resources/manuals/fm/fm7_15.pdf

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'C:/Users/.../fm7_15.html'

with open(url, "r") as ur:
    html = ur.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

headers_30 = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class":
                                "s30"})
headers_33 = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class":
                                "s33"})
headers_20 = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class":
                                "s20"})

df30 = pd.DataFrame(headers_30,columns=["column"])
df30.to_csv('headers_30.csv', index=False)

df33 = pd.DataFrame(headers_33,columns=["column"])
df33.to_csv('headers_33.csv', index=False)

df20 = pd.DataFrame(headers_20,columns=["column"])
df20.to_csv('headers_20.csv', index=False)
```

There are 3 classes that compose the different headers (s30,s33,s20). I have managed to save them as csv's but the problem is that it also extracted all the associated html tags. What is the best way to go about extracting just the header text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to extract the text from the elements:

```
headers_30 = [i.text for i in soup.find_all("p", {"class":"s30"})]
headers_33 = [i.text for i in soup.find_all("p", {"class":"s33"})]
headers_20 = [i.text for i in soup.find_all("p", {"class":"s20"})]
```

Instead of:

```
headers_30 = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class":"s30"})
headers_33 = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class":"s33"})
headers_20 = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class":"s20"})
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks. I was trying to use the ".text" function on my header objects which weren't lists. What is the best way to get rid of the " u'\.....' " notation that surrounds each line?

Comment: Try changing i.text to i.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore'). The strings you are getting are Unicode this will convet them to ascii. I'm surprised pandas doesn't recognise Unicode though.